# Check all assertion and verifications when using mockk verification together with assertion libraries

Tags: kotlin, mockk, kotlintest

I want the test to report all assertions and verifications. So both the `mockk` verification **AND** the the assertion library (in this case, `KotlinTest`) assertions should run and not shortcircuit.

In other words I don't want the test to stop ...

```
verify(exactly = 1) { mock.methodcall(any()) } // ... here
success shouldBe true // how can I check this line too
```

nor ...

```
success shouldBe true // ... here
verify(exactly = 1) { mock.methodcall(any()) }  // how can I check this line too
```

How to do this? I am open to use just one tool if I can do both with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your comment, you said you are using `KotlinTest`.

In KotlinTest, I believe you can use [`assertSoftly`](https://github.com/kotlintest/kotlintest/blob/master/doc/reference.md#soft-assertions) for the behavior you want:

> Normally, assertions like shouldBe throw an exception when they fail. But sometimes you want to perform multiple assertions in a test, and would like to see all of the assertions that failed. KotlinTest provides the assertSoftly function for this purpose.
>
> ```
> assertSoftly {
>   foo shouldBe bar
>   foo should contain(baz)
> }
> ```
>
> If any assertions inside the block failed, the test will continue to run. All failures will be reported in a single exception at the end of the block.

And then, we can convert your test to use `assertSoftly`:

```
assertSoftly {
    success shouldBe true
    shouldNotThrowAny {
        verify(exactly = 1) { mock.methodcall(any()) }
    }
}
```

It's necessary to wrap `verify` in `shouldNotThrowAny` to make `assertSoftly` aware of it when it throws an exception

Comment: The `shouldNotThrowAny` part was the missing piece for me, thanks a lot!